# Post data to logstash using http input

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

im trying to figure out how to post data to Logstash input from my browser using JavaScript.

**JavaScript Post in Json format** **:**

```
 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "????????????????";
 xhr.open("POST", url, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 var data = JSON.stringify({"test" : testdata123});
 xhr.send(data);
```

What Url should i be posting to if i want logstash to read this data?

**Logstash config file :**

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => ?????
  }
}
```

I am new to this and would like some advice on how to go about doing this.Please help?

Comment: What happens when you're goin ahead with the above logstash config? You have to give the server port which you want logstash to listen to.

Comment: The JavaScript needs to post to a port example Localhost:8590, does this need to be a Logstash port?

Comment: You could give any port which your logstash wanted to be listened. BUt make sure that you don't have any other applications running on that port.

Comment: Thanks, so if i set Logstash to listen to port :9200, then my javascript post should be to that port?

Comment: Yes that's right. But then `Elasticsearch` runs on that port as well right ? So make sure you give a port which other applications don't use it.

Comment: Elastic does run on that port but just giving an example. Yes you can add this solution as answer

Comment: @kulasangar I have another question, hoping you can help me out please. Link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161666/logstash-json-post-output?noredirect=1#comment69524754_41161666

Comment: i''ll have a look on it and get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `port` in the `tcp` plugin within your `input` in `logstash`, conveys the port on which logtash will be running on. So that you can access `logstash` using that particular `port`. Make sure you set a port, which isn't being accessed by any other applications within your server.

Comment: Also something to take into account is that ports 0-1024 can only be accessed by programs running as root. (which may or may not impact the current use case)